# How to integrate Xcode project with UI to Xamarin project

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have xcode iOS project with implemented `UI` on "storyboard". And i need to use that `UI` in "Xamarin project". Is any existing tools which can convert project to "Xamarin"?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no. Because the process is literally just including the storyboard, and if necessary, open it in XCode and create the references and let XCode and Xamarin Studio sync. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any tools that will convert the whole project but here is a tool that can convert portions of your code:

http://razum.si/automagical/

You will still need to rewrite some portions and do fixes on the converted files.